# Http get request through socks5 | EOF error

Tags: ssl, go, proxy, httprequest, socks

**What I'm trying to do:**
Build a package (later usage) that provides a method to execute a get-request to any page through a given socks5 proxy.

**My problem:**
When ever I try to request a page with SSL (https) I get the following error:

> Error executing request Get https://www.xxxxxxx.com: socks connect tcp 83.234.8.214:4145->www.xxxxxxx.com:443: EOF

However requesting `http://www.google.com` is working fine. So there must be a problem with the SSL connection. Can't imagine why this isn't working as I'm not very experienced with SSL-connections. `End of file` makes no sense to me.

**My current code:**

```
func main() {
    // public socks5 - worked when I created this question
    proxy_addr := "83.234.8.214:4145"

    // With this address I get the error
    web_addr := "https://www.whatismyip.com"

    // Requesting google works fine
    //web_addr := "http://www.google.com"

    dialer, err := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", proxy_addr, nil, proxy.Direct)
    handleError(err, "error creating dialer")

    httpTransport := &http.Transport{}
    httpClient := &http.Client{Transport: httpTransport}

    httpTransport.DialTLS = dialer.Dial

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", web_addr, nil)
    handleError(err, "error creating request")

    httpClient.Timeout = 5 * time.Second

    resp, err := httpClient.Do(req)
    handleError(err, "error executing request")

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    handleError(err, "error reading body")

    fmt.Println(string(b))
}

func handleError(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

So what am I missing in here to deal with ssl-connections?

Thank you very much.

---

**Edit 1:**

In case someone would think this is an issue with `whatismyip.com` I've done some more tests:

- https://www.google.com

  - EOF error
- https://stackoverflow.com

  - EOF error
- https://www.youtube.com/

  - EOF error

Comment: It works fine with google because the URL you set for google is using `http` and not `https`. I've tried with `https://www.google.com` with your code and it doesn't work either...

Comment: @math2001 Well that's what I'm saying in my question as well. And the core question here is **why** and **how to deal with https**.

Comment: It means the SOCKS server disconnected without sending you anything. Check its logs to find out why.

Comment: @MichaelHampton `whatismyip.com` isn't my website so I can't check their logs. Also that website isn't the only one that's throwing an error. In fact it happens everywhere SSL is used.

Comment: I said check the logs of the SOCKS server, not the destination website you were trying to visit through it.

Comment: You _are_ running this on your _own_ SOCKS server, right?!? When I ran the code you pasted, I got the interesting webserver error message which reads in part: `<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>`

Comment: @MichaelHampton that also isn't the case. The proxy in my code is a public one. According your error: That sounds to me like my code is limited to http-connections.

Comment: You definitely should be using your own SOCKS server for this. That way you can actually figure out what the problem is, without having to make wild guesses. And yes, I agree, it looks like your code is limited to HTTP connections. I don't have the solution right now, but hopefully this gets you closer to understanding the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connection between your program and your socks5 proxy goes not through SSL/TLS

So you should change line
`httpTransport.DialTLS = dialer.Dial`
to
`httpTransport.Dial = dialer.Dial`

I checked https://www.whatismyip.com and https://www.google.com.
URLs are downloaded fine.
For test I set up 3proxy service on my server, test your code with fixed line and check 3proxy logs.

All made requests was in proxy server logs.

If you need more help - please let me know, I'll help

---

**Things to notice**:

- Socks5 proxies need to support SSL connections.
- The code from the question won't work with this answer as the proxy (used in the code) isn't supporting SSL connections.

Comment: I've edited and added my own research about this. Unfortunately you either haven't tested my own code with your solution or you just haven't set any comment about **why my comment with your solution still isn't working**. My edit should clear that out. I've picked another proxy `79.106.133.123:1080` and the request all of the sudden worked as expected.

Comment: Also take into account that `httpTransport.Dial` is depracted. I don't know how that should get handled since then so I leave this open to you to say something about it (if you know). Away from this 2 comments my problem is fixed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I used 3proxy for test, if you need I'll send full code + /etc/3proxy.cfg